# No such file or directory grub-eltorito.img

Tags: buildroot, rootfs, iso9660

I have still problem with:
**grub-eltorito.img: No such file or directory**

> Generating root filesystem image rootfs.iso9660
>
> /usr/bin/install -D -m 0644 fs/iso9660/grub.cfg /mnt/Seagate/Praca/buildroot-2016.05/output/build/rootfs.iso9660.tmp/boot/grub/grub.cfg
>
> /bin/sed -i -e "s%**KERNEL_PATH**%/boot/bzImage%" /mnt/Seagate/Praca/buildroot-2016.05/output/build/rootfs.iso9660.tmp/boot/grub/grub.cfg
>
> /usr/bin/install -D -m 0644 /mnt/Seagate/Praca/buildroot-2016.05/output/images/grub-eltorito.img /mnt/Seagate/Praca/buildroot-2016.05/output/build/rootfs.iso9660.tmp/boot/grub/grub-eltorito.img
>
> /usr/bin/install: nie można wykonać stat na „/mnt/Seagate/Praca/buildroot-2016.05/output/images/grub-eltorito.img”: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu
>   fs/iso9660/iso9660.mk:160: polecenia dla obiektu '/mnt/Seagate/Praca/buildroot-2016.05/output/images/rootfs.iso9660' nie powiodły się
>
> make: *** [/mnt/Seagate/Praca/buildroot-2016.05/output/images/rootfs.iso9660] Błąd 1

There is my diffstat:
[diff](http://pastebin.com/4HyY4uAW)

I watched this file:
[grub2.mk](https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/diff/boot/grub2/grub2.mk?id=8f609ed603220e0ac0ef9a45b0214eb87ab85d1e)
 and delete line associated with **GRUB2_IMAGE_INSTALL_ELTORITO** but still not working.
How I can resolve this problem?

PS. Sory for my English but is not fairly good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in buildroot. I suppose you selected EFI as the grub2 platform? It seems that that is not supported at the moment. Would you care to report this issue either on the [buildroot mailing list](http://mailto:buildroot@buildroot.org) or in the [buildroot bug tracker](https://bugs.busybox.net/index.cgi)?

Comment: I chose option x86-64-efi in buildroot. Yes, I would like to resolve problem because and write a engineering work. I never use bug tracker so I will have problem with this.